# conda broke dnf, yum, yum-deprecated; I tried them all: reinstalled dnf, python etc. Fedora 29

Tags: python, anaconda, fedora, dnf

I just installed conda under root (I know, it's bad -- I did not know what would happen...). I am on Fedora 29.
When I type `dnf` into shell I get

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 29, in <module>
import libdnf.transaction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libdnf'
```

similarly with `yum. yum-deprecated` instead gives

```
File "/usr/bin/yum-deprecated", line 36
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python path seems to be the right one, i.e. */usr/bin/python*
but if I type just $python it uses the anaconda one.
Already checked *.bashrc*, *.bash-profile* files, correct `$PATH`, no new export.
I also tried reinstalling dnf, yum, python from rpm, doesn't change much.